# How to upload multiple files with Carrierwave using a single json/array column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, carrierwave, jquery-file-upload

I have an Activerecord model in a Rails 3 project to which I'm trying to upload multiple file attachments, I'm using MySQL as the db.

In the current release of Carrierwave [it talks about](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/README.md) now being able to store multiple uploaded files in a single a ActiveRecord field of array or Json types - so I'm attempting to get this approach to work and I'm unclear on how to implement this.

In all the tutorials/[railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload?view=asciicast)/SO questions I've only found people using the more traditional `has_many` relationship to link to separate attachment records.

In my case I have an Invoice record where each invoice needs to have multiple "jobfile" attachements and I'm following the example in the Carrierwave README.

I've added a json field to the model:

```
class AddJobfileToInvoice < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :invoices, :jobfile, :json
  end
end
```

In the form view I've enabled mutiple uploads

```
<%= form_for(@invoice, html: {class: 'invoice-form', multipart: true}) do |f| %>
.....    
<%= f.file_field :jobfile, multiple: true%>
```

In my posted params I can see the correct array of multiple uploads coming through as `params[:invoice][:jobfile]` which gives:

```
params[:invoice][:jobfile]
=> [#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000065996f0     @original_filename="test1.gif", @content_type="image/gif", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"invoice[jobfile][]\"; filename=\"test1.gif\"\r\nContent-Type: image/gif\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20150311-33374-1cqjv3i>>, 
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000659a0c8 @original_filename="test2.gif", @content_type="image/gif", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"invoice[jobfile][]\"; filename=\"test2.gif\"\r\nContent-Type: image/gif\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20150311-33374-15stv05>>]
```

I've then cached the files as per the Carrierwave readme and saved the model

```
@invoice = Invoice.new(params[:invoice])
@invoice.jobfile = params[:invoice][:jobfile]
@invoice.save
```

However as soon as I save the invoice model I get a `Jobfile You are not allowed to upload nil files` error

Can anyone post or point me to a working example of getting Carrierwave to use a single JSON (or array) field to upload multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

So I believe the problem is that MySQL doesn't support the Json or Array field types so it looks like the current Carrierwave implementation only works on PostgreSQL.

Somehow my migration proceeded without throwing an error but instead silently created a string field instead - allowing single file uploads to work but not multiple file ones.

When I tried to duplicate the entire process from scratch in a fresh VM it did throw a meaningful error making the problem pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of SQLite3 or MySQL has no column type *json* as it possible in PostgreSQL. So, you can try change type from *json* to *text*

```
class AddJobfileToInvoice < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :invoices, :jobfile, :text
  end
end
```

In my case it wokrs.

Comment: That did not work for me. I also tried to use `t.string :houseimages, array: true` but it is not stored as array, all the images are saved on houseimages[0], while 1,2,3.. are nil

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio, try remove array: true